# If Statement in Twig with a Stringnumber

Tags: php, if-statement, twig

i using Twig as Templatelanguage and stay before a Problem.

I have an Array with the Key **information_id**. This Key have the Number 10 as Value. The Typ of this Number is a string in the Array.

Now i want, if the information_id equal to 10, choose a other ID as if informaton id is not equal 10. If the information_id equal 10 i want to display the ID **information-information**. If information_id is not equal 10 i want to display the ID **information**.

I get the Value of information_id over a GET-Parameter.

I have looked in the TWIG Documentation how i can create this Statement. But all things which i tryed don't works for me.

Every Time the Statement choosing the ID **information** although the Value of information_id is 10.

My Twig
Code

```
{% if information_id == '10' %}
    {% set id = 'information-information' %}
  {% else %}
    {% set id = 'information' %}
  {% endif %}
<div id="{{ id }}" class="container">
</div>
```

What i doing false?

Greetings,
Stef

Comment: If `information_id` the array or already the string? Test with `{{ dump(information_id) }}`

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. My Mistake was that i dont add the information_id to the Array in my Controller which get used at this Twig File. Now i have added it and it works.